# How to repeat programming lines in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

... by the term "programming lines" I mean parts of code .

I am currently creating an UI using c# and XAML. But the XAML code is getting longer and longer, so I realised that if I could somehow set inside the code or store separately, repeatable parts of code and use them every time I needed, the whole XAML  code would be shorter and clearer.

For example, let's say that I have a specific label which I want to repeat in several points of the code:

```
  <Label Name="myLabel" Content="something">
  </Label>
```

How could I possibly apply and repeat that label inside my XAML code?

Comment: You can create your own styles or/and control templates for repetitive controls, place it into resource dictionaries and reuse it when needed

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski A short example would be appreciated if that wasn't much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quick example of how the XAML code can be shared between different views/windows. Create a `ResourceDictionary`, define the shared properties/styles/control templates, like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="TitleStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Than you can add this dictionary to App/Window `MergedDictionaries` to use them, like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Please, note that this is just a quick example to briefly explain the idea. You can also have look at [`Style.TargetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.targettype?view=netframework-4.8) docs to see explanation between `TargetType` and `x:Key` in styles